# F# function multiple return value

Tags: f#

Curious about the syntax used in this example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/get-started-command-line) within the file Library.js

My question, is the getJson function returning multiple values without a tuple?

Any link to F# documentation that explains this syntax would be nice. thanks.

```
open System.Text.Json

let getJson value =
    let json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(value)
    value, json
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question, is the getJson function returning multiple values without a tuple?

Yes to the first part, no to the second. The comma on the last line makes these two values a tuple.

You may think from online examples that a tuple is like `(1, 2)`, but it’s just as fine to remove the parentheses if the expression is only on one line. In this case, `value, json` is the tuple.

Parentheses are used to disambiguate the order of evaluation. For instance, `1, “two”, “three”` is a three-tuple of an int and two strings, but `1, (“two”, “three”)` is a two-tuple of an int and the 2nd type being another two-tuple of two strings.

The Microsoft Learning link appears to always use parentheses in the examples. This post goes a little further, and has a bit more to say on tuple deconstruction as well: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/tuples/.

Here’s more on parentheses (thanks Brent!): [if it has a comma, it’s a tuple](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/troubleshooting-fsharp/#dont-mix-up-tuples-with-multiple-parameters).

Comment: Thanks. When I copy examples, I typically have to remove superfluous noisy parentheses, and not just around tuples. The rules of thumb here is, number one, [if it has a comma, then it is a tuple](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/troubleshooting-fsharp/#dont-mix-up-tuples-with-multiple-parameters), and second, parentheses are for precedence, as in algebra. They are not for constructing tuples, nor for arguments. Learning material should emphasize these things strongly, but very rarely do so, and so we see a lot of noisy code out there.

Comment: Thanks @benttranberg, I’ve updated my answer to clarify that.